# JS Slice() doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove the last characters from the following html code

```
<tbody><tr><tr>1<td><label for='depart1'>Department 1</label><br /><input type='text' id='depart1' class='textbox large' value='IT' /><br><label for='Courses_for_depart1'>Course for Department 1</label><br /><textarea id='Courses_for_depart1' class='textarea large' >OS</textarea></td></tr></tbody>
```

with the following code

```
addHtml.slice(0,-13);
```

It should remove `</tr></tbody>` But it removes only `></tbody>`

how to get rid of this strange behavior.

## update

```
addHtml=$("#departments").html();

<table id="departments">
                    <tbody><tr><tr>1<td><label for='depart1'>Department 1</label><br /><input type='text' id='depart1' class='textbox large' value='IT' /><br><label for='Courses_for_depart1'>Course for Department 1</label><br /><textarea id='Courses_for_depart1' class='textarea large' >OS</textarea></td></tr></tbody>              </table>
```

The above snippet is copied form view source code of chrome.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem. It removes `</tr></tbody>` for me.

Comment: What is stored in `addHTML`. How is `addHTML` defined?

Comment: .slice or .splice? http://prntscr.com/72yaed .splice only works on arrays.

Comment: Seems to work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/vao3x1g5/

Comment: @Ankit: I know and pointed that above, since the .slice of his code works, I suspect he is perhaps using the wrong operator? despite it shouldn't even return anything at all.

Comment: @Ankit: being honest I had ninja-edited my comment too about 2 seconds after I've posted it! :P Then, something like a minute later, I saw your comment. Anyway, maybe the OP either has other "hidden" characters or some spaces after </tbody>?

Comment: Seems like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: @Ankit please look at my updated question

Comment: Oh, the OP edited the code. He probably has some blank spaces, perhaps there? http://prntscr.com/72ycxo . Please try: `addHtml = addHtml.trim();`

Comment: @briosheje I have tried with trim and it is not working.

Comment: @DharanBro: then you probably have tabs there, as @IanBrindley suggested. Try `addHtml = addHtml.replace(/\t/g,"");` despite I really have no idea of what you could be having there, even if tabs seems to be the closest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably white space between the closing `</tbody>` tag and the `</tr>` tag. Try something like this:

```
addHtml = addHtml.trim();
var tbody = '</tbody>';
var t1 = addHtml.indexOf(tbody)+tbody.length;
var t2 = addHtml.lastIndexOf('</tr>');
var len = t1-t2;
var newString = addHtml.slice(0,-len); // This will have the string without the </tr> </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your addHTML contains spaces at the end and the beginning, so you need to trim all the spaces at start and end before using slice function so use

```
$.trim(addHtml).slice(0,-13);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vao3x1g5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As a possibly safer alternative, you could do this in two steps:
1) find the last `</tbody>` in the string, then slice up to it.
2) find the last `</tr>` in the remaining string, then slice up to that.
[String.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)